# How to print all callers ancestors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tracing a bug in Javascript,

And want to know where is the original root cause,

But the function calls are too deep.

I use this way to find the first caller.
`arguments.callee.caller....`

How to print all the callers in a time ?

Thanks

Comment: Use your browser development tools, place breakpoints to follow the code.

Comment: The console usually gives you the call tree when an uncaught error occurs.

Comment: As @elclanrs suggested, use a breakpoint and look at the call stack.  [Debugging JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

A) Insert a `debugger;` statement on its own line in your JavaScript (at a point where you'd like execution to pause). Open Chrome Dev Tools and reload your page.

Or:

B) Open Chrome Dev Tools, select the `Sources` panel, open the relevant (JS) file, click on a line number to add a breakpoint, and reload your page.

And then:

Inspect values by hovering over them in the upper `Sources` panel (and clicking the resultant popup to drill down into them) or by clicking them the `Scope Variables` and `Watch Expressions` panels on the lower-right.

While debugging, you can also insert further breakpoints (the blue pentagons), step into/through/over function calls, and run code-checks in the console.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging
https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools